# Dynamically Define Variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

```
arrayName = @"Blah";
NSArray (array(arrayName))= [something or other];
```

After defining a variable name called "arrayName", which I wish to the name of an array to be it's condition. Is the code defining the NSArray possible?

P.S. The code is pseudo code.

Comment: That is not proper objective-c syntax. Check out the [developer library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/) or some other tutorials to get the basics right.

Comment: @user2609670 why are you doing this? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: It's an honest question. I am wondering if it's possible to define new variables while the program is running. P.S. I know it's not good syntax, it's just a problem with logic, not with the ACTUAL syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you want to use an `NSMutableDictionary` then you can have your variable names as the keys, and assign them their specific values.

but what you are asking isnt possible